How to determine 3 scenarios using argparse
How to determine 3 scenarios using the same switch -f in the same script using argparse, say script is called script.py

just run the scirpt no -f switch
script.py

-f is passed but no argument
script.py -f

-f is passed and has a argunment too
script.py -f /tmp/blabla


I tried but looks like one or the other works but not all these 3 scenarios.

Yes! exactly what I wanted :-), thanks a lot!!!
